# NVidia Graphics Card Error 43?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, windows-10-upgrade, nvidia-graphics-card, display-driver

I am using the NVidia GeForce GT745M card, and I am receiving the following error code in Device Manager:

```
Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)
```

Looking at the details of the device, I see a Problem Code of `0000002B` and the following output for Status:

```
01802400
DN_HAS_PROBLEM
DN_DISABLEABLE
DN_NT_ENUMERATOR
DN_NT_DRIVER
```

I am unsure of how to fix this and how to proceed.

I am currently running driver version 9.18.13.4990 (NVidia Driver 349.90) on Windows 10 Technical Preview build 10041.

Disabling and enabling the device will clear the error flag, but nothing detects the device.

Comment: I am encountering the same issue on the official release of Windows 10, with both my Nvidia 765m drivers and Intel 4600 drivers. Both display adaptors give a Code 43, external monitors do not work, and most games and GPU intensive applications will not run. I have tried removing and reinstalling the drivers completely, rolling back to 8.1 and trying the upgrade again, and everything else short of what the manufacturer suggested: Factory Reset (come on Razer, I'm not doing *that*).

Comment: Added a bounty. The formatting of which... is apparently not editable?

Comment: I have the same problem with my GTX 1080 and after install UPSilon Mega Tec driver and software for UPS. Windows 1909. Uninstall the UPS driver solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to find a solution that worked for me (at least for now):

1. Download [Display Driver Uninstaller](http://www.wagnardmobile.com/DDU/) and the latest [NVIDIA Drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) for my card. **The OEM drivers will not work!!**
2. Reboot into Safe Mode and uninstall the PhysX Engine and the GeForce Experience.
3. Reflash BIOS to known working version. (Thank you [NVIDIA Forums!](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/654599/geforce-mobile-gpus/-gtx-760m-driver-for-asus-n56jr-s4044-laptop-with-/5/))
4. Boot into regular mode and install the NVIDIA drivers and all the related software.

---

Apparently ASUS laptops have an issue where BIOS updates and Windows 10 can sometimes cause Code 43s to appear.

In my specific case, I even had to go back to BIOS version 214 for the Asus Q550LF. The flash utility would not accept an older BIOS, so I had to force it with `winflash /nodate bios.214` [(src)](https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?11438-How-to-downgrade-your-Bios-using-Winflash).

Comment: Windows 10 has been released. I would suggest you install the release version too. Also I don't recommend a 3rd party uninstall application as Nvidia graphics installer is capable of doing a fresh install of graphics drivers.  Also on 29th July Nvidia released updated drivers for Windows 10 to address from DX12 issues - you may have not got these, at time of writing that was verison 353.62 - would suggest you hold on to the latest WHQL drivers for the future.  On http://www.geforce.co.uk/drivers you can signup for driver alerts.  Also I would opt never to install the drivers offered by the OS.

Comment: @albal: I am running W10 release. DDU was used because the NVIDIA Installer does not clean _everything_ up. It left a fair bit behind in my (quick) research. I am running the latest NVIDIA drivers, and I am using the GeForce Experience to keep my drivers updated.

Comment: Interesting, unfortunately there is no BIOS update for my system.

Comment: @zeel Can you downgrade to a known-working version, or did you not flash a BIOS with your laptop?

Comment: I have not, as far as I can tell from searching, there has never been a copy of the BIOS distributed for my machine.

Comment: This fix didn't work for me. My understanding is that the fix only applies to UEFI motherboards and/or only to those with multiple GPUs.

As for myself, I tried several different driver versions from Nvidia and Windows Update. When installing a new driver, my screen will go blank and stay blank, but my typical background processes are still running. Upon rebooting, it's always code 43. I even reformatted and fresh installed Windows 10.

Comment: @mach How did you solve your problem? I have the same Nvidia Code 43 problem here: http://superuser.com/questions/1156317/nvidia-graphics-card-displays-high-resolution-only-in-safe-mode

Comment: @Ryan Replied to you at your link

Comment: @zeel I added a bounty to my question linked in the previous comment. Maybe you could help and win it? Thanks.

Comment: @Ryan Unfortunately, my solution was not great: complete factory restore. I have to believe a better way exists, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: @zeel Thanks! EVGA is preparing to replace mine too.